# Question regarding straight

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I was recently playing poker online. In the board was 2,A,3,Q. In my hand I had 5,K. Why didn't it say I had a straight? Isn't Q-K-A-2-3 5 in a row? Or does it not carry on after A?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, of best five cards. OP is asking about the often confusing dichotomy of the ace in the ranking of hands.

Comment: It is a dupe, as this exact hand is covered in the definition of a straight in one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. In Texas Hold 'em, and some other (but not all) variations, an ace can be both one position higher than a king *and* one position lower than a two, but **never** both in the same hand.

This specific case is mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight):

> Under high rules, an ace can rank either high (e.g. A♦ K♣ Q♣ J♦ T♠ is an ace-high straight) or low (e.g. 5♣ 4♦ 3♥ 2♥ A♠ is a five-high straight), but cannot rank both high and low in the same hand (e.g. Q♠ K♠ A♣ 2♥ 3♦ is a high card, ace, not a straight).

Comment: Your last sentence appears to contradict your previous sentence, and it is wrong to say that an Ace is never a "1" in Texas Hold-Em, as A 2 3 4 5 is still a straight in Hold-Em.